# How to find your private key with your 12 Word Password Phrase and the depositing Address?

Tags: mycelium-wallet

I use MyCelium v14 for iOS. In the past 72 hours, the address could not synchronize because the servers are "down, unpaid for".

I have used my 12 Word to access MyCelium via Android App and Jaxx, and now Exodus. Here is my issue, I have both transaction Hashes and addresses of where my coin are and I have my 12 Words, the issue is you're able to Add more Accounts on MyCelium, for example I can have my Main Account, Account 1, Account 2, Account 3 etc and they have have their own generated addresses and all of that sort.

I've been speaking with the Android developer and he's been discussing that I will need to keep creating new accounts and depositing coin to each new account so I can create a new account until I find the account with my bitcoins. This has been very frustrating since I been using MyCelium for 5 years now and they have stopped updating the iOS version for 2 years, yes I should've moved to a different address but unfortunatley I've placed all my eggs in one basket.

Am I able to find my private key/account with my 12 Word Passphrase and my depositing addresses/transaction hashes that the coin is currently stuck in?

Comment: I would suspect anyone who claimed to be a developer of Mycelium and who gave that advice is either incompetent, criminal or a liar. I may be overly suspicious but it seems very poor advice.

Answer (score 1):

The 12 words encode a seed that can be [used to derive bitcoin addresses](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). There are an infinite number of derivation paths you can take using any one seed, so knowing the right derivation path will be necessary to recover your funds.

A quick google search tells me Mycellium uses the [BIP44 derivation path](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki): m/44'/0'/0'/0

So you just need to find some software that allows you to specify the path being created, and point it to the correct one.

> I've been speaking with the Android developer and he's been discussing that I will need to keep creating new accounts and depositing coin to each new account so I can create a new account until I find the account with my bitcoins.

You most definitely do not need to send any bitcoin to any wallet you generate, in order to determine if it is the derivation path you are looking for. Upon being supplied the correct path, the wallet should show you your transaction history as per normal, as long as it is correctly synced with the network.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you - download the page and use it offline (scroll to the bottom for instructions).

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/